# Why is continuity like "the light of a lamp"?

Tags: mahayana, impermanence, nagarjuna, causes

> 22. Because the continuity of the aggregates is similar to the light of a lamp, therefore the very existence  or non-existence of an end is
>     unreasonable.

https://www.stephenbatchelor.org/index.php/en/verses-from-the-center

Is it because the action of the lamp is contained in light, so we cannot conceive of its end, and its end neither exists nor doesn't (same as a four sided triangle: it's a nonsense phrase).

---

Before his dedication (30), Nagarjuna concludes

> 29. And because all things are empty, about what and in whom do views such as that of permanence spring forth?

Does that mean enlightenment is not a view, but the impossibility of a view about an end: rejecting the idea that things either end or do not.

If an end is inconceivable then so is 'permanence', so the opposite of an end is not "permanence" but buddha-nature.

Comment: I am baffled because it seems what I've been saying all along may well be on point to everything the Karika says

Comment: That's some intellectual babble. Reality is not a linear progression. Just practice meditation and you will see.

Answer (score 2):

No. The light of a lamp is a well-known Buddhist metaphor for continuity of information-causation (what Nagarjuna refers to as "the divine"), since at least The Questions of King Milinda:

> --“Can there be any rebirth where there is no transmigration?”
> --“Yes there can, **just as a man can light one oil-lamp
> from another** but nothing moves from one lamp to the
> other; or as a pupil can learn a verse by heart from a teacher
> but the verse does not transmigrate from teacher to pupil.”

and

> The king said: ‘He who is born, Nāgasena, does he remain the same or become another?’
>
> [Nagasena:] ‘Neither the same nor another.’
>
> [King:] ‘Give me an illustration.’
>
> [N] ‘Now what do you think, O king? You were once a baby, a tender thing, and small in size, lying flat on your back. Was that the same as you who are now grown up?’
>
> [K] ‘No. That child was one, I am another.’
>
> [N] ‘If you are not that child, it will follow that you have had neither mother nor father, no! nor teacher. You cannot have been taught either learning, or behaviour, or wisdom. What, great king! is the mother of the embryo in the first stage different from the mother of the embryo in the second stage, or the third, or the fourth ? Is the mother of the baby a different person from the mother of the grown-up man? Is the person who goes to school one, and the same when he has finished his schooling another? Is it one who commits a crime, another who is punished by having his hands or feet cut off ?’
>
> [K] ‘Certainly not. But what would you, Sir, say to that? ’
>
> The Elder replied: ‘Neither I am what is now the grown up, nor was I what was the tender tiny baby, flat on its back. But all these are tied in one by means of this body.’
>
> [K] ‘Give me an illustration.’
>
> [N] ‘Suppose a man, O king, were to light a lamp, would it burn the night through?’
>
> [K] ‘Yes, it might do so.’
>
> [N] ‘Now, is it the same flame that burns in the first watch of the night, and in the second?’
>
> [K] ‘No.’
>
> [N] ‘Or the same that burns in the second watch and in the third?’
>
> [K] ‘No.’
>
> [N] ‘Then is there one lamp in the first watch, and another in the second, and another in the third?’
>
> [K] ‘No Sir. But thanks to that lamp the light shined all the night through.’
>
> [Nagasena:] ‘Just so, O king, does the continuity of dharmas connect. One emerges, another dissolves, connecting as it were without [a clear boundary between] the previous and the next, thus the former-consciousness and the next-consciousness cannot be categorized as either the same nor as different.’

Comment: I've heard of that before. do you mean that the teaching of continuity being like a lamp has no end. that's a novel but bad reading imho

Comment: In chapter 27 Nagarjuna muses about extreme  views, such as a person existing - or not existing - after death. Please reread the chapter until you understand it.

Comment: I think I understand it already! can you clarify what you mean, other than "you're wrong" please?

Comment: "Because the continuity of the aggregates is similar to the light of a lamp, therefore the very existence or non-existence of an end [of an "entity" such as "a person"] is unreasonable."

Comment: yeah I quoted that too! I read it to mean that its end was inconceivable. what do you think it means?

Comment: What we call "entity" is a process of continuous non-discrete causal development, non-separate with the rest of the world. Therefore, the notion of "end" has no ontological referent.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I am not separate from the tips of my fingers, but both of us have an end. do you mean that it is not separate from the **whole**. but then "27. How can one part of that-which-is-clung-to perish while one part does not perish?  Likewise, that is unreasonable"

Comment: Nagarjuna talks about temporal termination, not spatial boundaries. When your body dies, it becomes food for worms, nutrition for grass and trees etc. Preservation of energy if you wish.

Comment: And many of your thoughts become the thoughts of your children, students, and/or of the readers of your books etc. The non-profits you started still operate after your death. The social movement you launched keeps helping people. Likewise, the river you polluted keeps killing everyone. Continuity of information and causation.

Comment: all true, but I feel you didn't convince me of your implied claim. that's fine tho!

Comment: I think I answered the question in the title and explained what Nagarjuna meant. Feel free to ask another question if you have more.

Comment: what do you mean by "you're wrong"? I don't know if you mean that ends don't exist with svabhava, but do nevertheless exist. if so, what is your argument for it from the Karika?

Comment: My "No." in the beginning of my answer referred to your "Is it because the action of the lamp is contained in light, so we cannot conceive of its end" - because that's not what Nagarjuna meant, and I showed what he did.

Comment: nowhere does he mention lighting another lamp. in what way does the end of the light not exist? I really don't think Nagarjuna is denying anyone is reborn. is that what you think he means?

Comment: He uses a well-known, standard, metaphor that is virtually always used when discussing reincarnation or personhood in Buddhism.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be going anywhere. in what way does the end of the light not exist?

Comment: The end of light in an infinite series of lamps, lit from one another? Because that's what he refers to (without spelling it out, because that was common knowledge to all Buddhists he was writing it for)

Comment: so we are reborn an infinite number of times? is that what you mean? when he says continuity is like light I took him to be making a claim about continuity, not light

Comment: I'm saying, rebirth is a crude metaphor for the endless continuity of information-causation.

Comment: so he compares it to "light" because light is crude?

Comment: No, he compares it to light of a lamp, lit from another lamp, and so on, because it's an image of "passing on" of information/causation.

Comment: ok I get it! he compares it to light because it can be passed on to another lamp. I'm not sure why you think that doesn't contain my interpretation tho. that's what confused me, you leading with "no"

Comment: The conclusion you reach in your answer is correct, but the way you arrive there from the karika is wrong, this is why as any teacher I cannot give you a passing grade.

Comment: well you're not my teacher, we're equals on-line at least, so I'm free to disagree with your claim that anyone can "arrive there... wrong".

Comment: That's fine. At least we attained some semblance of understanding for once.

Comment: hahah true. so does the abhidharma say that light itself (leave lamps alone for a moment) has no end?

Comment: It's not the same light nor is it different. It doesn't have end nor is it endless.

Comment: I was just referring to something I half remember reading in Va. adbhidhrama about the nature of light compared to sound or taste. maybe I'll find some notes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add to Andrei's answer, I quote [this passage](https://www.lionsroar.com/thich-nhat-hanh-zen-teacher-who-popularized-mindfulness-in-the-west-dead-at-95/amp/) written by Thich Nhat Hanh, the Vietnamese Zen master who recently passed away:

> This body of mine will disintegrate, but my actions will continue me…
> If you think I am only this body, then you have not truly seen me.
> When you look at my friends, you see my continuation. When you see
> someone walking with mindfulness and compassion, you know he is my
> continuation. I don’t see why we have to say “I will die,” because I
> can already see myself in you, in other people, and in future
> generations.
>
> Even when the cloud is not there, it continues as snow or rain. It is
> impossible for the cloud to die. It can become rain or ice, but it
> cannot become nothing. The cloud does not need to have a soul in order
> to continue. There’s no beginning and no end. I will never die. There
> will be a dissolution of this body, but that does not mean my death.
>
> I will continue, always.

Comment: I think any disagreement centres on how it's not clear what the relation of the conventional self to the world is. no-one thinks the world itself ends when we die except solipsists.